# Como faço para disparar um alert com o click de um botao em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, timer

```js
let iniciar = document.getElementById("iniciar")
let pausar = document.querySelector('.pausar')

iniciar.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert('Cliquei no iniciar')
}, true);

pausar.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  alert('Cliquei no pausar')
});
```

```html
<button id='iniciar'>Iniciar</button>
<button class='pausar'>Pausar</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do pedro, é legal separar JavaScript de html. Ficaria assim:

```js
document.getElementById("btnAlerta").addEventListener('click', MeuAlerta);

function MeuAlerta() {
  alert('Escreva a mensagem');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnAlerta">Alerta</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tente isso:

```js
function MeuAlerta() {
  alert('Escreva a mensagem');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btnAlerta" onchange="MeuAlerta();">Alerta</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado.... =)

Comment: Esse código não funciona.